# Cron jobs error "wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0"

Tags: php, cron

I get the error_log

> http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by
>   allow_url_fopen=0 in {my dir}/fetch.php

No problem running fetch.php in the web browser.

After a Google of the problem you need to turn on the fopen, which I have done in the php.ini. Have php.ini in the same folder fetch.php

php.ini

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
register_globals = On
safe_mode = Off
max_input_time = 900
memory_limit = 256M
```

This i my Cron job

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/{CpanelUsername}/public_html/{RootFolder}/cronjob/fetch.php
```

{CpanelUsername} and {RootFolder} is of course correct path instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check with which php.ini your php is running. it can be done by using function:

`phpinfo()`

`loaded configuration file`

also check allow_url_fopen is true or not under `Core` section.

If it's the same file in which you have edit, then make sure you have restarted apache after setting the values in php.ini